# Help identifying a SMD chip on a motor controller board

Tags: surface-mount, motor-controller

I have a wood chipper that stopped working. It has a universal motor driven by a circuit board with a handful of components. The input is 220VAC (red+blue wires), and the intended output is unknown to me (yellow wire).

Right now, the board delivers nothing on the output wire.

There is a TRIAC delivering power to the output wire, and there is a small surface mounted mystery chip that drives the TRIAC.

The easiest solution would of course be to just replace the entire board, but I haven't been able to find a replacement board locally, so my next hope is to repair the board.

The motor seems fine: 10 MΩ across each winding. The TRIAC also seems to be fine.

The "mystery chip" has a dark spot in the center, so I suspect this is where the problem lies.

However, I can't make out the text on that chip, and I was hoping that perhaps someone here may recognize it..?

It looks like the first row of text on the chip starts with "HT6F" of "HTGF".

Here are some photos:

[image: underside of board]

[image: mystery chip]

[image: triac]

[image: overall circuit diagram]

[image: chip after cleaning]

Comment: 10MΩ is not 'fine' in motor terms - that's essentially an open circuit for a winding, and possibly an indication of insulation breakdown if measured to ground. You typically expect windings to be in the single-digit ohms for reasonable size AC motors including universal/series.

Comment: Can you post a diagram of how this PCB is connected into the whole system? I imagine it's little more than a soft start.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica I added a simplified circuit diagram of how the board is connected. There are two switches: an operator switch, a "lid switch" to prevent it from starting when the lid is open, and a motor overcurrent device which I drew as a switch. The board is fed with 220V AC, and there is a single lead from the triac output to the motor. The other motor lead goes to neutral. I will measure the motor again to make sure I didn't mix up the measurement.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Yes, a soft start would make sense as the motor drives a steel wheel with knives. If that is the case, I should be able to find a different soft start to replace it with.

Comment: Yes, that board is likely just a soft start (although it could also have overcurrent protection). For a *test only*, removing the load from the motor (e.g. the spinning wheel with knives, or perhaps just the belt if it's belt drive) and bypassing the soft start could answer the question.

Comment: Can you wash it off with some isopropanol and a toothbrush and take a clean photo? Given the row of five though holes just right to it, I’d guess it’s a microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks both, I will test that tomorrow: 1) Will re-measure the motor windings, 2) Will try to clean the mystery chip, and 3) Will check if the motor runs without physical load with this board bypassed.

Comment: I have also ordered a standard off-shelf soft starter that I can use as a replacement if this is indeed a soft starter. It makes 100% if it is.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica I re-measured, and all three motor windings are 10MΩ.  I also tested bypassing the board  land the motor runs fine. I think you are right: this is probably just a soft start, so I have ordered a generic soft start as a replacement. Thanks!!

Comment: @winny I cleaned it, but it is still not any clearer. (Photo of the cleaned chip above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@winny suggested it could a MCU, based upon the row of five through holes just to the right of it.

Where the row of five through holes could be for in-circuit programming.

Based upon the picture the characteristics of the in-circuit programming are:

1. A MCU which can be operated from a 5V supply.
2. Pins PA0 and PA2 are used for the programming.
3. The is one pin on the row of five though holes where from the picture can't make out the label on silk screen but connected to pin 4 of the MCU based upon the tracks.

Based upon the above "clues" then **could** be a Holtek HT66F03C/ HT66F04C/HT68F03C/ HT68F04C. Found a [Preliminary datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809031732_Holtek-Semicon-HT66F03C_C83549.pdf) where the *In Circuit Programming* contains the following matches the row of five though holes:

[image]

The datasheet shows pin 4 contains the RES pin in the `SOP-B` 8-pin packages. If the device really is a MCU, then the other complication with replacing it is the need to load the correct program which means you need:

1. A suitable programmer.
2. The programming file to read. Where:

   - If the MCU has been damaged you might no longer be able to read the existing program from it.
   - The manufacturer might have disabled readback of the program, to prevent it being "cloned".

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think you are right, as the last three characters look like "04C". Based on this and the comments from others, I have ordered a generic soft start board. Thanks everyone!